# How to code an Azure HTTP Trigger function that passes parts of its incoming message to a Service Bus Queue?

Tags: azure-functions

I am setting up some Azure HTTP Trigger functions to receive JSON data.

I would like to access pass some of the data onwards to a Service Bus Queue for downstream processing.

I have been able to add the outbound binding to a Service Bus, but are not able to place code to place a message on the queue from the HTTp Trigger function without getting a 500 Internal Server Error. Is this due to the async nature of the function?

How can I achieve a call-HTTP-Trigger-that-passes-data-onwards-to-a -ServiceB-Bus-Queue functionality?

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {

        context.log('Incoming data from Webhook' + req);
        context.bindings.outputSbMsg = "Message placed on Service Bus Queue";
        context.log('Message placed on Service Bus Queue');

        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};
```

I did try deploying just as you did, but unfortunately I still get the 500 Internal Server Error even when just running a GET query.

Here is what the files look like at the monent:

**function.json**

```
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "iotcwebhookdispatchersbns_SERVICEBUS",
      "name": "outboundSBQMsg",
      "queueName": "observations-sbq"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    var message = "This is a test SBQ message - from an Azure function!";
    context.bindings.outboundSBQMsg = message;
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: "This code is to send message to service bus."
    };
};
```

**local.settings.json file**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "iotcwebhookdispatchersbns_SERVICEBUS": "Endpoint=sb://iotc-webhook-dispatcher-sbns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=MiIv52YQ6plMVt35vPvx9U5DmsQbTvUXamaeZ/fA2Eg="
  }
}
```

When configuring the outbound Service Bus Queue I found it strange that I could choose the Service Bus Queue Namespace from existing Namespaces. I could not in the next step choose actual Queue, even though the observations-sbq had been created before.

Entering some other queue name, like testqueue, did not work either. It was not created and the same 500 Internal Server error occures, even when testing the function directly in the portal.

The error messages:

[image]

Does that mean that local.settings.json files has not been used/deployed?

Excerpts from the log file:

*2020-08-28T07:03:46.194 [Information] JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2020-08-28T07:03:46.249 [Error] Executed 'Functions.iotc-webhook-dispatcher' (Failed, Id=e248ae01-7a82-485e-bcfe-00ebee6496e0, Duration=14ms)
Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'iotcwebhookdispatchersbns_SERVICEBUS' is missing or empty.
2020-08-28T07:07:08.256 [Information] Executing 'Functions.iotc-webhook-dispatcher' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=222a675f-8b16-4720-b807-bcc9834d7ddc)
2020-08-28T07:07:08.818 [Information] JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2020-08-28T07:07:10.107 [Error] Executed 'Functions.iotc-webhook-dispatcher' (Failed, Id=222a675f-8b16-4720-b807-bcc9834d7ddc, Duration=1067ms)
Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'iotcwebhookdispatchersbns_SERVICEBUS' is missing or empty.*

Comment: It seems your code is no problem, can you show your function.json file?

Comment: And are you running the code locally or on azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works fine on my side:

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
        "name": "outputSbQueue",
        "type": "serviceBus",
        "queueName": "testqueue",
        "connection": "str",
        "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    var message = "This is a test message.";
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue = message;
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: "This code is to send message to service bus."
    };
};
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "str":"Endpoint=sb://testbowman.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx="
  }
}
```

Then you will find one message comes into the service bus queue:

[image]

Comment: @TobiasPersson So you are running in azure?

Comment: @TobiasPersson It should have some error output, can you show it?

Comment: I code in Visual Studio Code and upload it to en existing Function App / Function.

Comment: I added the contents of my files to my original post above. I can't see anything weird in them and now difference between your code and mine. What about the "select existing Service Bus Queue" issue?

Comment: @TobiasPersson Ok, so please go to check the details error. First, go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, then click in `LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\yourtriggername>`, you will find log files there.

Comment: @TobiasPersson If you follow my solution and still get error, that means error doesn't come from the code.

Comment: How do I get an image into a commenT Added it above instead.

Comment: @TobiasPersson You can put the image in your question, then you will get the url, then just use `[description](the link)`. Like this: [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf7Js.png)

Comment: I added an log entry excerpt above. The SBQ Connection String seems correct on my side. Is it not being uploaded perhaps?

Comment: @TobiasPersson When you deploy to azure, local.settings.json will not be used. You need to put the settings here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xITa.png

Comment: It actually works fine now - excellent! I added the Connection String in the Function App Configuration and now it works just fine. While on the matter, do you know how I "deliver" the message to the queue in JSON format?

Comment: @TobiasPersson JSON format? I don't think it works like this, it just stores data, it doesn't involve the file format. You can store the content of the entire json file in the service bus queue, receive it and convert it when you need to use it.